# redirect to php page if fields are empty

Tags: php, forms, validation, redirect

I want to redirect to the page which has a form when user submit the form without any parameters, also I want to return an error message, how can I redirect from controller to the form?

```
<form action="controllers/Customer.controller.php" method="post">

    <label for="cellPhoneNo">cell phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="cellPhoneNo" class="textField"/>

    <label for="telephone">telephone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" class="textField"/>

    <input type="submit" name="searchCustomer" value="بحث"/>
</form>
```

and here's the Customer.controller.php page

```
  if(trim($_POST['cellPhoneNo']) == "" && trim($_POST['telephone']) ==""){

  //include('Location:index.php'); //what I supposed to write here?
   echo "empty";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the structure of your framework, you can use php's [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
if(trim($_POST['cellPhoneNo']) == "" && trim($_POST['telephone']) ==""){

   $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fields cannot be empty!';
   header('Location: myformlocation.php');
   exit(); 
}
```

And just above your form:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'] )) : ?>

<div class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['error'];?></div>

<?php 
unset($_SESSION['error']); 
endif; ?>


<form action="controllers/Customer.controller.php" method="post">
```

So, whenever the form submits, if fields are empty, the form page is reloaded and, since $_SESSION error is now set, it will be displayed. You might want to make a function out of $_SESSION['error'] displaying, so you won't writing all that code in each form.

**EDIT after comment:**
Uhm, I'm not really sure to understand your question, you can use either $_GET:

```
header("Location: ../index.php?page=customerSearch");
```

and you retrieve it in index with 
`$pageToInclude = $_GET['page'];`  //properly sanitized

or use

```
$_SESSION['pageToInclude'] = 'CustomerSearch'; 
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Fields cannot be empty!';
header('Location: myformlocation.php');
....
```

and in index you use

```
$pageToInclude = isset($_SESSION['pageToInclude']) ? $_SESSION['pageToInclude'] : 'someotherdefaultpage';
```

Comment: How can I go one step back in the folders since index.php is outside controllers folder?

Comment: @Alaa `../index.php` should do the trick. You can either supply a full path, `http://mysite.com/index.php`

Comment: @ Damien Pirsy, how can pass a parameter to index.php, since I make like this  include("subpages/$pageToInclude.sub.php"); in index, I make $pageToInclude="CustomerSearch" befor   header('Location: ../index.php'); but id doesn't work!

Comment: what is this warning "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\crm\controllers\Customer.controller.php:5) in C:\AppServ\www\crm\controllers\Customer.controller.php on line 11 "

Comment: @Alaa that warning is because you're outputting something before your header is sent; it can be an echo, a withespace, whatever. Check at line 11

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST)){
    $cont=true;
    //cellPhoneNo
    if(!isset($_POST['cellPhoneNo']) || strlen($_POST['cellPhoneNo'])< 13){ //13 being the telephone count
        $cont=false;
        $_SESSION['error']['cellPhoneNo']='Cell phone is required & must be 13 in length';
        header('Location: ./index.php');
        die();
    }
    //telephone
    if(!isset($_POST['telephone']) || strlen($_POST['telephone'])< 13){ //13 being the telephone count
        $cont=false;
        $_SESSION['error']['telephone']='Telephone is required & must be 13 in length';
        header('Location: ./index.php');
        die();
    }

    if($cont===true){
        //continue to submit user form

    }else{
        header('Location: ./index.php');
        die();
    }
}else{
    header('Location: ./index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't check for is_int in telephone numbers, as usually values like +39 02.. or 347/123456 or whatever are acceptable supplied values for phone numbers. Phone numbers are not integers

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, what is this warning "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\crm\controllers\Customer.controller.php:5) in C:\AppServ\www\crm\controllers\Customer.controller.php on line 11 "

Comment: that means on line 5 output has started, considering session_start() is on line 2 you must have white space above the `<?php`