# PHP if field empty then dont send form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP form setup on my website that includes a "honey pot" to trap bots etc. However we are finding recently that people are submitting blank forms that just contain a name and email - not sure what the purpose of these is but they are becoming increasing frequent and I would like to prevent these.

Here is my PHP script. I'd like to add a "if name, email, message" is blank then redirect to uh-ho.html. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'Website Enquiry';
$from_name = $_POST['name'];
$from_email = $_POST['email'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = "From: $from_name\nEmail: $from_email\nTelephone: $phone\nMessage: $message\n\nThis enquiry form was sent from $location";
$robotest = $_POST['robotest'];

if($robotest)
  $error = header('Location: /index.html');
else{

  if($from_name && $from_email && $message){
    $header = "From: Project Customs";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
      $success = header('Location: /thank-you.html');

    else
      $error = header('Location: /uh-ho.html');
  }

  else
    $error = header('Location: /uh-ho.html');
}

if($error)
  header('Location: /uh-ho.html');
elseif($success)
  header('Location: /thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess you want to set `$error` to true or false

Comment: `header()` does not have a return value http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: why not use javascript to check it in onsubmit funciton

Comment: if($_POST['name']=="" || $_POST['email']="" || $_POST['message'] ==""){ header('Location:uh-ho.html'); }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect to php page if fields are empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971690/redirect-to-php-page-if-fields-are-empty)

Comment: replace `$error = header('Location: /uh-ho.html');` with `header('Location: /uh-ho.html');` and `$success = header('Location: /uh-ho.html');` with `header('Location: /uh-ho.html');` meaning remove assigning header return to variable. ` if( $name !== '' && $message !=='' && $email !=='')` do the rest

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest first is using one of CAPTCHA service ([Google captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)) to filter spams,

then for the code I suggest the following edit :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
  // I suggest that you edit these lines of code to check if the values of $_POST are set before assigning them here
  // something like $name = (!empty($_POST['name']))  ? $_POST['name'] : "";
  $to = 'email@email.com';
  $subject = 'Website Enquiry';
  $from_name = $_POST['name'];
  $from_email = $_POST['email'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $message = "From: $from_name\nEmail: $from_email\nTelephone: $phone\nMessage: $message\n\nThis enquiry form was sent from $location";
  $robotest = $_POST['robotest'];


  $location = 'Location: /index.html';

  if(robotest) {
    if(!empty($from_name) && !empty($from_email) && !empty($message)) {
      $header = "From: Project Customs";
      if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        header('Location: /thank-you.html');
        exit();
      }
      header('Location: /uh-ho.html');
    }
  }

  header('Location: /uh-ho.html');
}
```

Note:

header() function doesn't return any value so the use of this function in your code is invalid, the edit suggestion is a better way working with redirect in PHP.

Comment: You have missed `$robotest` condition!

Comment: @ShaunakShukla read the first line of the answer, I do believe it was done on purpose.